# How to add media queries in carousel element tag p

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

How to add media queries in carousel element tag p.My code

```html
<span><strong><p class="text-center">Aktuelnosti u proizvodnji malina</p></strong></span>
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: @screen-xs-max){
  .text-center p{color: red;font-size:11px;}
```

But not work p media query for 320px media screen.

Comment: <span><strong><p class="text-center">Aktuelnosti u proizvodnji malina</p></strong>
              </span>

Comment: <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="...">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
           <span><strong><p class="text-center">Aktuelnosti u proizvodnji malina</p></strong>
              </span>
          </div>
        </div> 
      .....

Comment: Title does not decrease with the change of the window size has remained the same. Carousel is responsive and p tag is not. How to do it

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your css style.
You want to select a paragraph with class "text-center"
 So the right way to do it is this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    p.text-center {
        color: red;
        font-size: 11px !important;
    }
}
```